# Passing Vector to another class

Tags: c++, class, vector

As the title suggests I am trying to send a vector from one class to another.. Here is some sample code...

```
class Deck
{
    public:

    //constructor
    Deck(){}
    ~Deck(){} //deconstructor

//global for setting deck size
int SetDeckMultiplier;

    //Card SetUp
            //access vector
        std::vector<int> GetCopyOfVector(){return cards;}
            //set deck size based on multiplier
        void SetDeckSize();
            //shuffle card vector
        void shuffle();

    //End Card Setup

     protected:

     private:
std::vector <int> cards;

};
```

This essentially sets up a vector, fills it with ints, than shuffles the ints.

I have a second class...

```
class Dealer: public Deck
{
  public:



  void Hit();
  void GetStoredDeck()
  {

    std::cout << cards.size() << std::endl;
  }
  void DealCard();
  void DealerScore();
  void IniDeal();
  void CardPositions();

  private:

};
```

I am attempting to pull the vector into this class, so that dealer can use the ints. I can make the vector protected, but the .size() is 0. Is there a way to pass it into this class after it is filled and shuffled in the first class?

Edit:

I do not have much code for the functions in classes. I was just working off a skeleton setup.

Deck.cpp

```
void Deck::SetDeckSize()
{
      for (int i = 0; i < (52 * SetDeckMultiplier); i++)
        {
        cards.push_back(i);
        }

    //set card values
      for (int i = 0; i > (52 * SetDeckMultiplier); i++)
      {
        cards[i] =  i;

      }

}

void Deck::shuffle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (52 * SetDeckMultiplier); i++)
        {
       int r = i + (rand() % ((52 * SetDeckMultiplier) - i)); // Random remaining position.

       int temp = cards[i]; cards[i] = cards[r]; cards[r] = temp; //swap cards

       while (cards[i] >= 52) cards[i] = cards[i] - 52; //loop to ensure correct number for display

        //std::cout << cards[i] << std::endl;//display random cards.. for now
    }
}
```

This is the code I have to fill the vector and shuffle the elements.

I would like to take the shuffled vector and use it in the dealer class. This way the dealer can get the next element in the vector and do what need to be done with it.

What I was saying about the size() is that if I make the vector protected instead of private, I can use the vector via inheritance, but it is the empty vector not the filled and shuffled one.

Comment: Could you please show the code that is using these classes? What you're trying to do is not totally clear.

Comment: Are you saying your `getCopyOfVector()` function is returning a vector of size 0?

Comment: Is your dealer a deck? :)

Comment: I wanted my dealer to be able to control the deck.. IE, get the next card and deal it ;)

Comment: It's a 'has a' relationship as opposed to an 'is a'. So your deck should be a member variable of the Dealer (composition). Not a base class.

You also might find std::random_shuffle() handy too. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

Comment: OT: discover the joys of `std::random_shuffle()`

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add create *cards* into `cards` in Deck constructor. This is just a simple sample which shows shared data among base and derived class:

```
class Deck
{
public:
  Deck() : cards{1,2} {}    // C++11 supports initializer list
  virtual ~Deck() {}        // better declare base destructor as virtual

protected:                  // derived class can access protected base members
  std::vector <int> cards;  
};

class Dealer: public Deck
{
public:
  Dealer()   // Deck default constructor is called 
  {
  }

  void GetStoredDeck()
  {
     std::cout << cards.size() << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Dealer dealer;
  dealer.GetStoredDeck();   // you should see 2 cards now?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, you can get rid of the `Dealer` constructor as long as the base has a default constructor, and in C++11, you can initialize `cards` with those values: `Deck() : cards{1, 2} {}`

Comment: the constructor just initializes the cards though right? I need the shared data to include the fact that it was shuffled too. I will try it and figure it out ;) thank you

Comment: @chris I like that, like c++11 initializer list, updated my answer according to your comment. thanks

Comment: @user1956980 you can call shuffle function in constructor, because cards are generated already in `member initilizer list`

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your code (and assuming you have made `cards` protected in `Deck`), you could use your Dealer class like this:

```
Dealer dealer;
dealer.SetDeckSize();
dealer.shuffle();
dealer.GetStoredDeck();
```

However, your class design is not looking good, as pointed out by @Troy.
A dealer is not a deck, so `Dealer` should not be a subclass of `Deck`. Instead, `Dealer` should contain a field of the Deck class, like this:

```
class Dealer
{
  public:
  void Hit();
  void DealCard();
  void DealerScore();
  void IniDeal();
  void CardPositions();

  private:
  Deck deck;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access to int vector `cards` in your derived class `Dealer`, you **must** declare it `protected`...

From your methods name, I guess `Deck::SetDeckSize()` is the guy that puts ints into `cards`.

So, I'd guess that you haven't called this method before calling `Dealer::GetStoredDeck()`.